# How can I remove line annotations behind cursor in Intellij 2019.1?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After updating to IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 on macOS I see behind the cursor the line commit message (or annotations). How can I disable it?

`<CURSOR> <USER>, <DATE> <TIME> <COMMIT MESSAGE>`

`<CURSOR> Name, 2019-03-07 09:41 ABC-1234 Did do something`

[image: I had to remove some parts]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have installed [GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) third-party plug-in which provides this feature:

> **Blame inlined in active editor** - show blame for line at caret in active editor

Either [disable](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html) the plug-in or configure its options as shown below:

[image: blame]

Answer (score 25):

Newer versions of intellij has a feature called "**Inlay Hints**".

Open `preferences` and search for it.

Uncheck those you don't want to see, probably "**Code author**"

[image]

Answer (score 7):

That isn't an IntellIJ IDEA feature.
You installed the [GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) plugin.

[image]

---

This is called Git *blame*.
You enable it by right-clicking the gutter area (if you configured a valid Git root)

[image]

And you disable it in the same way with *Close Annotations*

[image]

---

The displayed information can be altered using the *View* sub-menu

[image]

---

All the necessary IDEA examples/explanation can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html).
For your case, under the [Locate code author](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#annotate) paragraph.

Comment: Thanks but this points to the normal annotations. I mean the text shown behind the cursur, in the same way than the values while debugging, however just for the line the cursor is in.